# How to fix the error caused: pub get failed(69) During running futter doctor

Tags: flutter

I just downloaded and installed flutter SDK(archive). when I run the "flutter doctor" command on my mac m1 terminal I receive this error. pub get failed/exit code: 69
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naNbP.png)

i want to run futter doctor so as to create any flutter project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Related GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77892)

It looks like the code "69" means a network error. Please check your firewall and anti-virus software. There's the easiest way is to close your firewall and anti-virus software completely during you run `flutter doctor`.